# Java OpenGL only blue Textures

Tags: java, opengl, colors, textures

I've have a little Problem with Textures and OpenGL. I made a small .obj Loader (with Texture Loading) but everything is drawn blue. Example:

I load a Texture. I bind the texture with GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureId).
If I do:

```
    glColor3f(1f,1f,1f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(50f,0,-50);
glVertex3f(-50f,0,-50f);
glVertex3f(-50f,0,50f);
glVertex3f(50f,0,50f);
glEnd();
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
```

it draws a white quad ... but if I do:

```
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glColor3f(1f,1f,1f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(50f,0,-50);
glVertex3f(-50f,0,-50f);
glVertex3f(-50f,0,50f);
glVertex3f(50f,0,50f);
glEnd();
```

it draws a blue quad and everything else is blue too.

Maybe somebody knows a solution?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Solid color, wrong color, or color at all? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Everything is colored blue after I load one Texture so it has the wrong color. I want to load a normal Texture and draw it with the normal colors. I read something about RGB and BGR and I think that's my problem. But I don't know how to swtch between RBG and BGR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no texture because you didn't specify texture coordinates using `glTexCoord2f`.

The colors are wrong probably due to incorrect parameters to `glTexImage`.

Everything else is blue because, you are using the same texture for everything. Bind different texture or use the default texture 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem because you are not using the glTexCoord2f with each vertex. Please try this with each vertex because it can solve it as presently your color is not binding to all the areas.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I think I didn't explain it right. I don't want the loaded texture to be drawn on this quad. It was just an example. I wanted to show that after I bind 1 Texture, there is always a blue color on normal quads and Textures.

Comment: Now I tried to draw a red Texture on a quad. If the texture is colored red it turns into blue when I'm rendering it. If it's blue it turns into red. Maybe a problem with RGB and BGR?